# Does newly inserted document in MongoDB surely has "bigger" _id than older document?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, database

What's the algorithm for MongoDB to calculate the "_id" field. It looks it is incremental.

I'm wondering if it is safe to sort by "_id" field as sort by time the document inserted.

Answer (score 4):

The way ids are generated is described [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-The%5CidField). Turns out leading bytes are given to the timestamp, so probably the order of ids corresponds to the order of insertion (if we don't consider deviations in time between different machines).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to sort by order of insertion then you need to add your own field for timestamp or incremental counter. In a sharded set-up sorting by _id might not work.

Comment: Agreed. Even if there is a described way how ids are generated, they should be considered random.

Comment: This is not strictly true. ObjectId have a hard specification where *local* machine time is used as the leading part. From the same machine the order is guaranteed on a granularity of 1 second, from different machines this guarantee is no longer there. It is up to the developer to figure out if they can take advantage of it. Considering the ObjectId completely random can be appropriate but not always.